# JQuery Datatables serverside proccessing table doesn't refresh the content

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

When I open the page first time, it shows the results fine but when I use filtering or ordering a column etc. ajax method successfully returns the correct elements and json format looks correct but grid doesn't update the content. I initialized datatable in the following way:

```
$('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("_Index")',
    "bServerSide": true,
    "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "Konu" },
                    { "sName": "Şikayet" },
                    { "sName": "Kullanıcı Adı" },
                    { "sName": "Müşteri Adı" },
                    { "sName": "Müşteri Soyadı" },
                    { "sName": "Şirket Adı" },
                    { "sName": "Cevaplandı" },
                    {
                        "sName": "Cevap Ver",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                            return '<a href='+'@Url.Action("Edit")' + '/' +  
                                oObj.aData[7] + '>Cevap Ver</a>';
                        }
                    }
                ]
});
```

And in serverside:

```
public ActionResult _Index(jQueryDataTableParamModel table)
{
    var feedbacksList = (List<FeedbackAjaxVM>)AppService.QueryInfo("Admin", "GetFeedbackAjaxList", table);

    IEnumerable<string[]> feedbacks = from c in feedbacksList
                 select new string[] { 
                     c.Subject, 
                     c.Text, 
                     c.Username, 
                     c.CustomerName, 
                     c.CustomerSurname, 
                     c.CustomerFirmname, 
                     c.Response, 
                     c.Id.ToString() 
                 };

    return Json(new
   {
        sEcho = "1",
        iTotalRecords = feedbacksList.FirstOrDefault() != null ? feedbacksList.FirstOrDefault().TotalRecords : 0,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = table.iDisplayLength,
        aaData = feedbacks
    },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I think my problem is about clientside code but couldn't figured that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sEcho` is crucial to `Datatables` for rendering the data. The calls are asynchronous so `Datatables` needs to know the order of requests, this order is preserved by incrementing the `sEcho` variable in each server call.

However, you are returning 1 as sEcho all the time. According to `Datatable`, data with `sEcho` 1 is allready rendered so it is not rendering your data. You should return the sEcho value from `jQueryDataTableParamModel`. Simply, replace

```
sEcho = "1"
```

with

```
sEcho = table.sEcho
```

Comment: I've found the solution already. I temporarily wrote that value but I forgot to change it. Thx anyways, your answer is accepted, cool Iranian surname by the way :)